# CASE WHEN EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause, exists

I'm trying to create a field that if any of the committees listed under the study is DSMB then 'YES' if not 'NO'. I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

A study can have multiple committees attached to it but I want to keep it to one line.

However, this query is filtering out all the committees that do not have a DSMB committee.

I want all studies to show up, and have a yes if it has a DSMB and a NO if it does not.

```
SELECT STUDY,
    CASE WHEN
 EXISTS(SELECT COMMITTEE 
                FROM Database 
                  WHERE COMMITTEE = 'DSMB')
            THEN 'YES'
              ELSE 'NO'
                               END "DSMB"

FROM DATABASE
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use a window function:

```
SELECT STUDY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN COMMITTEE = 'DSMB' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) OVER (PARTITION BY STUDY) as "DSMB"
FROM DATABASE
```